# sns pairplot variable 'GrLivArea' output is blank

Tags: python, seaborn

I got my housing data from kaggle. I am trying to do a pairplot using seaborn. However I am not sure why `GrLivArea`  graph output is blank.

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=['GrLivArea', 'LotArea', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'GarageArea'], y_vars=['SalePrice'], height=8, aspect = 1, kind='reg')
plt.show()
```

Able to advise?

Comment: Have you check for nans in your dataset?

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem when using `sns.pairplot`.

Then I find the solution on `Github` [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2260).

By adding the parameter `diag_kind=None` in the `sns.pairplot` then the first plot could successfully build.

Comment: I prefer to put this kind of answer as a comment.

Comment: @MasoudRahimi Sorry, because I'm new here. I have not enough reputation to do that. But thanks!

Comment: Don't be sorry; you are welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your x-axis for the first plot starts from 0.0 and goes till 1.0. If you do the following:

```
sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=['LotArea', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'GarageArea','GrLivArea'], y_vars=['SalePrice'], height=8, aspect = 1, kind='reg')
```

then the plot will be empty for LotArea.

At first, I assumed it was due to empty values (NaNs) in your dataset. But, I checked it, and it does not seem to be the case.

The following **solution** should solve your problem:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=4)
sns.regplot(x='GrLivArea', y='SalePrice', data=df, ax=axs[0])
sns.regplot(x='LotArea', y='SalePrice', data=df, ax=axs[1])
sns.regplot(x='TotalBsmtSF',y='SalePrice', data=df, ax=axs[2])
sns.regplot(x='GarageArea', y='SalePrice', data=df, ax=axs[3])
plt.show()
```

While it is not a pairplot, you can plot each regplot as a subplot.